# Pass the username and password in URL parameters (Dart & Flutter)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parse-platform, back4app

I have a flutter app and I'm using back4app.com and Parse RESTful api to register my users, I have read their docs about logging in users but I dont know how to pass my username and password in URL parameters as JSON encoded :

I tried this method:

```
Future <void>loginMethod(String username,String password) async {

var url = Uri.parse('https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/login/$username:$password');


final response = await  http.get(url,  headers: {
          'X-Parse-Application-Id': kParseApplicationId,
          'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': kParseRestApiKey,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          
          
          },);


final exData = jsonDecode(response.body);

print(exData);
```

but  I've got some errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the **GET** method while sending your personal data to the server.
**GET** method data is sent data to the server followed by the **URL** like append with URL request which will be seen to everyone like below.

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/login/$username:$password');
```

This is how your personal data can be readable from a URL in a **GET** Method.

```
'https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/login/Mehran@metra.org:abcd12345'
```

For login requests, we should use the **POST** method. Because our login data is secure which needs security. When using the **POST** method the data is sent to the server in a bundle.

```
 Future loginMethod(String username,String password) async {
       var res = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://myshoppingapp.b4a.io/login/'),
            body: {"username": username, "password": password});
        print('res : ${res.body}');
       
        
if (res.statusCode == 200){ final exData = jsonDecode(res.body);
    
    print(exData);
return res.body;
} else{
final exData = jsonDecode(res.body);
    
    print(exData);
return res.statusCode;
}
        
   }
```

Comment: but in the Parse docs they said for the login users the right method is GET

Comment: No @DrBody  For login request we should use the POST method. Because our login data is secure which needs security. When use POST method the data is sent to server in a bundle. But in GET method data is sent to the server followed by the URL like append with url request which will be seen to everyone.

Comment: thank's alot for your assistance I'm using POST method for login and it works now.

Comment: If you are using get, you should pass the username and password as URL-encoded parameters:

Answer (score 1):

for HTTP basic authentication

```dart
final loginUrl = Uri(scheme: 'https', host: 'example.com', port: 8080, userInfo: 'username:password')
http.get(loginUrl)
```

but pass username and password via url is not recommended cause it's not safe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#access_using_credentials_in_the_url

so you should do it by using post formdata.